# Spacy ValueError: [E103] Trying to set conflicting doc.ents

Tags: python, spacy

I followed a tutorial on `SpaCy` to extract `spans` and overwrite `doc.ents` with the `spans` as below:

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Span
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')

COUNTRIES = ['Morocco', 'Mozambique', 'Myanmar', 'Namibia', 'Nauru', 'Nepal', 'Netherlands', 'New Caledonia', 'New Zealand', 'Nicaragua']
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)         # initialises the PhraseMatcher
patterns = list(nlp.pipe(COUNTRIES))
matcher.add('COUNTRY', None, *patterns)

text = 'After the Cold War, the UN saw a radical expansion in its peacekeeping duties, taking on more missions in ten years than it had in the previous four decades.Between 1988 and 2000, the number of adopted Security Council resolutions more than doubled, and the peacekeeping budget increased more than tenfold. The UN negotiated an end to the Salvadoran Civil War, launched a successful peacekeeping mission in Namibia, and oversaw democratic elections in post-apartheid South Africa and post-Khmer Rouge Cambodia. In 1991, the UN authorized a US-led coalition that repulsed the Iraqi invasion of Kuwait.'

doc = nlp(text)
for match_id, start, end in matcher(doc):         # Iterate over the matches
    span = Span(doc, start, end, label='GPE')     # Create a Span with the label for "GPE"  
    doc.ents = list(doc.ents) + [span]            # Overwrite the doc.ents and add the span

# Print the entities in the document
print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents if ent.label_ == 'GPE'])
```

However, the line `doc.ents = list(doc.ents) + [span]` caused the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-896d7076e05e> in <module>
      3 for match_id, start, end in matcher(doc):         # Iterate over the matches
      4     span = Span(doc, start, end)     # Create a Span with the label for "GPE"
----> 5     doc.ents = list(doc.ents) + [span]            # Overwrite the doc.ents and add the span
      6 
      7 # Print the entities in the document

doc.pyx in spacy.tokens.doc.Doc.ents.__set__()

ValueError: [E103] Trying to set conflicting doc.ents: '(74, 75, 'GPE')' and '(74, 75, '')'. A token can only be part of one entity, so make sure the entities you're setting don't overlap.
```

The error makes no sense because the entry Namibia in doc.ents has label as GPE, and so does the span Namibia have label as GPE, so that's consistent, not conflicting as error suggested. Does anyone know why I couldn't add two lists (`list(doc.ents` and `[span]`) together?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the label 'GPE' from `span = Span(doc, start, end, label='GPE')` and just use `span = Span(doc, start, end)` because `label` must be an integer.. Source: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/1167c303a01940c23a1a2d7c42fa4e8418f93f34/spacy/tokens/span.pyx#L94

Comment: Thanks for your quick suggestion, @amanb, but that caused another type of error `ValueError: [E103] Trying to set conflicting doc.ents: '(74, 75, 'GPE')' and '(74, 75, '')'. A token can only be part of one entity, so make sure the entities you're setting don't overlap.`

Comment: Strangely, I get `[('South Africa', 'GPE'), ('US', 'GPE'), ('Kuwait', 'GPE')]`. But I'm using the `en` model, don't know if that will make any difference.

Comment: Interesting. I tried to load `en` model like this `spacy.load('en')` but got this error `OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.` How did you install the `en` model? I used this in the command prompt `python -m spacy download en` but still unable to load `en` model.

Comment: okay, for the `en` model, you need to install it first with `python -m space download en`. Make sure that you do this as an admin at the command prompt. By the way, I'm still getting my same output with your model too `'en_core_web_md'` so that's sorted. I'm running spacy version 2.0.12 on Python 3.7, you may consider upgrading/reinstalling `spacy` if you have a lower version. Check the version with `spacy.__version__`

Comment: Just to clarify, you meant `python -m spacy...` not `python -m space...`? I believe I have admin right that's why I was able to install en_core_web_md. I have spacy version 2.1.6 with python 3.6 installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196763/discussion-between-amanb-and-jason).

Answer (score 3):

The following code works on Python 3 with Spacy 2.2.4 as well as 2.1.0:

Instead of using:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

use:

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
nlp = English()
```

The former gives an error while the following output is obtained if we use the latter:

```
[('Namibia', 'GPE'), ('South Africa', 'GPE'), ('Cambodia', 'GPE'), ('Kuwait', 'GPE'), ('Somalia', 'GPE'), ('Haiti', 'GPE'), ('Mozambique', 'GPE'), ('Somalia', 'GPE'), ('Rwanda', 'GPE'), ('Singapore', 'GPE'), ('Sierra Leone', 'GPE'), ('Afghanistan', 'GPE'), ('Iraq', 'GPE'), ('Sudan', 'GPE'), ('Congo', 'GPE'), ('Haiti', 'GPE')]
```